# Building Pylucene on ubuntu 14.04(trusty tahr)

Tags: python, ubuntu, lucene, ubuntu-14.04, pylucene

As per the installation [instructions](http://lucene.apache.org/pylucene/install.html), JCC is successfully built.

Dependencies Installed were:
ant, openjdk-7-jdk, python-setuptools, python-dev.

Then procedding to make pylucene, in "Makefile" i choose specs corresponding to Ubuntu 11.

```
# Linux     (Ubuntu 11.10 64-bit, Python 2.7.2, OpenJDK 1.7, setuptools 0.6.16)
# Be sure to also set JDK['linux2'] in jcc's setup.py to the JAVA_HOME value
# used below for ANT (and rebuild jcc after changing it).
PREFIX_PYTHON=/usr
ANT=JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64 /usr/bin/ant
PYTHON=$(PREFIX_PYTHON)/bin/python
JCC=$(PYTHON) -m jcc --shared
NUM_FILES=8
```

On executing "sudo make" command following error was encountered:

```
/usr/bin/python -m jcc --shared --jar lucene-java-4.6.1/lucene/build/core/lucene-core-4.6.1.jar --jar lucene-java-4.6.1/lucene/build/analysis/common/lucene-analyzers-common-4.6.1.jar --jar lucene-java-4.6.1/lucene/build/memory/lucene-memory-4.6.1.jar --jar lucene-java-4.6.1/lucene/build/highlighter/lucene-highlighter-4.6.1.jar --jar build/jar/extensions.jar --jar lucene-java-4.6.1/lucene/build/queries/lucene-queries-4.6.1.jar --jar lucene-java-4.6.1/lucene/build/queryparser/lucene-queryparser-4.6.1.jar --jar lucene-java-4.6.1/lucene/build/sandbox/lucene-sandbox-4.6.1.jar --jar lucene-java-4.6.1/lucene/build/analysis/stempel/lucene-analyzers-stempel-4.6.1.jar --jar lucene-java-4.6.1/lucene/build/grouping/lucene-grouping-4.6.1.jar --jar lucene-java-4.6.1/lucene/build/join/lucene-join-4.6.1.jar --jar lucene-java-4.6.1/lucene/build/facet/lucene-facet-4.6.1.jar --jar lucene-java-4.6.1/lucene/build/suggest/lucene-suggest-4.6.1.jar --jar lucene-java-4.6.1/lucene/build/expressions/lucene-expressions-4.6.1.jar  --use_full_names --include lucene-java-4.6.1/lucene/build/misc/lucene-misc-4.6.1.jar --include lucene-java-4.6.1/lucene/expressions/lib/antlr-runtime-3.5.jar --include lucene-java-4.6.1/lucene/expressions/lib/asm-4.1.jar --include lucene-java-4.6.1/lucene/expressions/lib/asm-commons-4.1.jar --package java.lang java.lang.System java.lang.Runtime --package java.util java.util.Arrays java.util.Collections java.util.HashMap java.util.HashSet java.util.TreeSet java.lang.IllegalStateException java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException java.util.NoSuchElementException java.text.SimpleDateFormat java.text.DecimalFormat java.text.Collator --package java.util.concurrent java.util.concurrent.Executors --package java.util.regex --package java.io java.io.StringReader java.io.InputStreamReader java.io.FileInputStream java.io.DataInputStream --exclude org.apache.lucene.sandbox.queries.regex.JakartaRegexpCapabilities --exclude org.apache.regexp.RegexpTunnel --python lucene --mapping org.apache.lucene.document.Document 'get:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;' --mapping java.util.Properties 'getProperty:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;' --sequence java.util.AbstractList 'size:()I' 'get:(I)Ljava/lang/Object;' org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter:getReader --version 4.6.1 --module python/collections.py --module python/ICUNormalizer2Filter.py --module python/ICUFoldingFilter.py --module python/ICUTransformFilter.py --resources lucene-java-4.6.1/lucene/analysis/icu/src/resources --files 8 --build 
  Warning: renaming static method 'toString' on class java.lang.Boolean to 'toString_' since it is shadowed by non-static method of same name.
  Warning: renaming static method 'toString' on class java.lang.Character to 'toString_' since it is shadowed by non-static method of same name.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.lucene.analysis.Tokenizer.pythonDecRef()
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1665)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/JCC-2.19-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/jcc/__main__.py", line 107, in <module>
    cpp.jcc(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/JCC-2.19-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/jcc/cpp.py", line 687, in jcc
    declares, typeset)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/JCC-2.19-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/jcc/cpp.py", line 1174, in code
    superMethod = find_method(superCls, methodName, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/JCC-2.19-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/jcc/cpp.py", line 310, in find_method
    if (e.getJavaException().getClass().getName() == 'java.lang.NoSuchMethodException'):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/JCC-2.19-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/jcc/cpp.py", line 51, in getJavaException
    return self.args[0]
IndexError: tuple index out of range
make: *** [compile] Error 1
```

On searching for the error few old [mailing list](https://www.mail-archive.com/pylucene-dev@lucene.apache.org/msg00994.html) were found which had similar errors but i was not able to get any hint out.

Can you please let me know what went wrong and how to fix it?

Do I need to install the java Lucene before installing pyLucene?

Comment: Yes, you do need Lucene before you can use PyLucene.

Comment: In fact, it appears that that is your problem. Symbols from the error (Namely, `NoSuchMethodException` among others) seem to indicate that JCC cannot fine Lucene's methods. Are you sure it's installed?

Comment: in case you are not limited to pylucene, but need just some search lib, have a look at whoosh. doesn't need java, pure python.

Comment: ask it on askubuntu.com

Answer (score 4):

Following these instructions (http://bendemott.blogspot.de/2013/11/installing-pylucene-4-451.html) got my system installed with `pylucene`. Before it was working, it was crazy and I had this problem ([Building Pylucene on ubuntu 14.04(trusty tahr)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24278627/building-pylucene-on-ubuntu-14-04trusty-tahr))  but after a thorough reformatting and a fresh ubuntu 14.04 i got it running:

```
# Downloads and extract pylucene
$ wget http://mirror.serversupportforum.de/apache/lucene/pylucene/pylucene-4.9.0-0-src.tar.gz
$ tar -zxvf pylucene-4.9.0-0-src.tar.gz

# Install dependencies
$ sudo apt-get install ant
$ sudo apt-get install g++
$ sudo apt-get install python-dev
$ sudo apt-get install python3-setuptools
$ sudo easy_install pip
$ sudo pip install setuptools --upgrade 

# Build and install pylucene
$ cd pylucene-4.9.0-0/jcc
$ sudo python setup.py build
$ sudo python setup.py install 
$ cd ..
```

Edit the file named "Makefile" located at the root of the pylucene-4.9.0 directory you just extracted and locate this line:

```
# Linux     (Ubuntu 11.10 64-bit, Python 2.7.2, OpenJDK 1.7, setuptools 0.6.16)
```

Uncomment lines in the Makefile as shown (if you are on linux) and save the changes:

[image]

Then continue with:

```
$ make 
$ sudo make install
```

Voila, it's installed. To test that `pylucene` works:

```
$ python
>>> import lucene
>>> lucene.initVM()
```